# How to verify fuse ampere rating

Tags: power-supply, pcb, pcb-design, fuses

Is there any method to verify the fuse ampere rating without destructing it .I know the fuses works on the principle of resistive heating .If there is any method to verify the ampere rating without destroying the fuse please answer

Answer (score 2):

If you can do a resistance measurement on the fuse, and at the low m\$\Omega\$ this will be, you will need to do a careful 4 terminal measurement. Then you can compare the measured resistances with those made on some example known fuses, or calculations based on the sizes of fuse wire.

Good luck with very careful measurements.